# Using an Olympus OM-10, why does film not advance for a couple of shots only?

Tags: film, troubleshooting, photography-basics, olympus, film-cameras

I have an Olympus OM-10. The film didn't seem to advance for a couple of shots somewhere after 15 or 16 shots. After that, it worked fine (based on the fact that the rewind knob didn't rotate as I pulled the advance lever). Sadly, those two shots were significant to me.

Please someone tell me that it could be okay. Please, can someone also explain why this would happen for two shots only?

Comment: Did you have double exposures on the processed roll, or only didn't see the rewind rotate?

Comment: I watched it to see if it's advancing and it didn't rotate. I don't do double exposures. I'm kinda new to film camera.

Comment: If the film didn't advance for two exposures, your film would have three exposures on one frame -- otherwise, it's just due to slack inside the cassette.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Photography Stack Exchange.  Please be sure to take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] so we're all on the same page regarding how this site works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rewind was rotating after you loaded the roll, and rotated again after the frames you're concerned, it's most likely that all that happened was that the rewind got moved and produced slack inside the cassette, causing the crank to stay still while the tension on the film caught up.

You won't be able to tell for sure if there was an actual problem until you process the film; if a mechanical failure caused the film not to advance for those two frames, you'll have a multiple exposure on whatever frame was in the gate at the beginning of that problem.  This is relatively uncommon, however, especially in cameras like the OM10 with mechanical film transport -- if those transport systems fail, they usually stay failed.

Comment: Yes it's probably because some kid touched the camera and I think I noticed he messed with the rewind a bit. You are absolutely right. But I didn't pay attention to it until you mentioned this issue. Thanks, much obliged.

Comment: @GhaithSh if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to any and all answers that help you and the check mark next to the one that helps the most. In general, you may want to wait 24 hours or so before clicking the check mark to see if any other answers come in that you may also find helpful.

Comment: It could also be that the kid fiddled with the rewind release button. In that case, you'll have a double exposure without mechanical failure.